# wget save-headers and file corruption?

Tags: http-headers, wget, corruption

Running `wget --save-headers` leaves the response headers at the top of the
downloaded file. However it seems that any file downloaded with this parameter
is corrupt, even if removing the headers.

```sh
$ wget svnpenn.github.io/img/2012/git.jpg

$ wget --save-headers -O- svnpenn.github.io/img/2012/git.jpg | sed '1,/^$/d' > git2.jpg

$ ls -l
total 136
-rw-r--r--+ 1 Steven None 65755 Jul  4 21:58 git.jpg
-rw-r--r--+ 1 Steven None 65753 Jul  7 11:35 git2.jpg
```

[image: git2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's the `sed` command that is doing it. If it edit the file with a hex edit it works fine. The following command works for me.

```sh
$ wget --save-headers svnpenn.github.io/img/2012/git.jpg
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 65755 (64K) [image/jpeg]

$ sed -b '1,/^\r/d' git.jpg > good.jpg

$ ls -l
total 136
-rw-r--r--+ 1 Steven None 66044 Jul  8 18:17 git.jpg
-rw-r--r--+ 1 Steven None 65755 Jul  9 17:53 good.jpg
```